# How to create a vertical timeline

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I need something like this:

[image: Picture of vertical academic timeline. The listed major is on one side of a center vertical line with the dates on the other side. Which side the major and dates are on alternates. Each entry also has a motorboard hat on the vertical line.]

As you can see one of major is right, the next is on the left, etc. The years do the same.

I wrote this HTML & CSS code:

```css
.full div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 130px;
  height: 50px;
}

.full div:nth-child(odd) {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="full">
    <div class="d1">university 1</div>
    <div class="d2">year 1</div><br>
    <div class="d1">university 2</div>
    <div class="d2">year 2</div><br>
    <div class="d1">university 3</div>
    <div class="d2">year 3</div><br>
    <div class="d1">university 4</div>
    <div class="d2">year 4</div><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

At first sight yes, it's working fine as I expected but it's not.

Problems are:

1. I can't center align no mater what I do.
2. At extra small size the `div` goes down, not side by side.
3. If I use a class like `col-xs-6` it's not working as I except.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zke68ao2/)

Just resize window to understand what I'm saying.

Comment: Note that you're not using the Bootstrap grid system correctly. Anything inside of a `<div class="row">` should be in a `.col` as well. In your question you've put it in a row but not a column. *Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows.* - http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this: hopefully it is close to what you need.

https://jsfiddle.net/zke68ao2/1/

```
.full{
  display: inline-block;
}
.full div{
      display: inline-block;
      width: 130px;
      height: 50px;
      text-align:center;
  }

  .full div:nth-child(odd):not(br){
      float: left;
  }
  .full div:nth-child(even):not(br){
      float: right;
  }
```

Comment: thanks dude. i just update my code with yours and it's work fine :) . you can check my online code if u want to. thanks again